# DirectoryIterator listing in alphabetical order

Tags: php

I'm doing a directory listing in alphabetical order using `DirectoryIterator` but in the production environment the listing is not in alphabetical order. I tried some parameters like `asort()`, etc. but it didn't work. Anybody know?

Localhost with **PHP 7.2.10**

Production with **PHP 5.2.17** (yes, legacy)

Code:

```
<?php
        $dir = array();
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator("PASTAS/");
        
        @ksort($dir);
        foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
            
            if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
                echo '<a href="PASTAS/'. $fileinfo->getFilename().'" class="list-group-item">'. $fileinfo->getFilename().'</a>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, **dir** is not an array of strings, so you can't sort it this way.
The strings (names) are in **dir[index]->getFileName()**.

So you should do the following steps:

1. Make an **$DirNames** array
2. Sort this array
3. Display this array

   ```
    $dir = array();
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator("PASTAS/");

    $DirNames = array();
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) 
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot())
            $DirNames[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();

    sort($DirNames);

    foreach($DirNames as $name)
        echo '<a href="PASTAS/'. $name .'" class="list-group-item">'. $name.'</a>';
   ```